Is aqua jogging on mat or water treadmill best?
I have knee issues and have been encouraged to look at aqua therapy by the doctors. I am considering getting something like an endless/therapy pool for walking and swimming. Some seem to have a pad you jog on against the current of the water, while others have an water treadmill. Interested to know the pros and cons of both.
